# How do i target an input button by a class

Tags: css, button, input

I am trying to target an input button by the class, however when i call the class in my CSS it does not work. How can this be done? So When i call the stat class in my input button it doesn't work.

CSS

```
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style-type: none;
text-decoration: none;
}

header, nav, section, aside, footer, article {
display: block;
}

body {

}

.container {
margin:0px auto;
background-image: url(back.png);
width: 1200px;
padding-top:10px;
height: 2000px;
}

.thenav {
background-color: #3b63d3;
height: 85px;
opacity: 0.9;
position: relative;
}

input[type=text], input[type=password] {
font-weight: bold;
margin: 0;
font-size: 8px;
height: 10px;
padding: 3px 5px 3px 5px;
color: 162354;
}

/* Stats Button */
form input[type=button] {
background-color: #6cd171;
color: blue;
border-radius: 6px;
font-weight: bold;
border: none;
margin-top: 20px;
margin-left: 20px;
padding: 2px 2px;
font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
 }

.stat input[type=button] {
background-color: grey;
color: #008cff;
border-radius: 6px;
font-weight: bold;
border: none;
padding: 1px 2px 2px 2px;
}
```

HTML

```
<span>put html code here</span>
```

Comment: Please add your HTML.

Comment: If the input itself has the .stat class then your selection is wrong. Remove the input[type=button] and it should work.

Comment: I added a some text, no flags for me, and now you can simply replace mine

Answer (score 1):

no need for space when the class is in the input.

```
input[type=button].stat{} or .stat{}
```

Comment: `.stat` by itself wouldn't be enough to override the specificity from OP's `form input[type=button]` selector.

Comment: You assume the `stat` is set on the `input`, which no one can know since we don't have the markup

Comment: I did, and no where it says the input has the class ... it says _by a/the class_, which can be either on the input or any other element

Comment: when i call the class in my CSS it does not work... in css we can understand what he is saying.

Comment: What work or not in your CSS is irrelevant, and no, we can't know by the CSS, as the statement `.stat input` says it should be a parent but it might be a sibling, such as a label, which would need one of the sibling selectors

Comment: Don't guess, answer questions when you have enough info to do so

Comment: hey so yeah i actually figured it out before and yeah it was the space that i added. I know I shouldve added my HTML but im finding it hard to put two pages of code on here.

Answer (score 1):

When you have a space between `.stat` and `input` you're looking to select an `input` element that is a child of `.stat`. You need to combine the two selectors.

Use `input[type="button"].stat {}`.

---

Below is a ***general*** example of how selector relationships work. Notice that your original CSS selector behaved like the third example.

```css
/* Targets ANY element with a class of .stat */
.stat {
  color: red;
}

/* Targets ANY input element with a class of .stat */
input.stat {
  color: green;
}

/* Targets ANY input inside of an element with a class of .stat */
.stat input {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<input class="stat" type="text" name="text-0" value="123abc">

<div class="stat">
  
  <p>
    My text is red. I inherited my color from <code>.stat</code>.
  <p>
  
  <input type="text" name="text-1" value="123abc">
  
</div>
```

Comment: `.stat` by itself wouldn't be enough to override the specificity from OP's `form input[type=button]` selector.

Comment: Ah yes, missed that selector. Updated.

Comment: First you assume the `stat` is set on the `input`, which no one can know since we don't have the markup, second, I don't see why we need yet another _general_ way how the selector works, there must be hundreds already, to close as duplicate

Comment: So an example of how selectors work is bad? It might be a bit extraneous, but how is it a negative?

Comment: Solving OP's question with an explanation how its particular selectors work is good, which in itself is general, but we can't as we don't know how it can be related since we don't have the markup, which was what I meant _why yet another_ ... and never said it was bad nor negative

Comment: @LGson sorry im having trouble figuring out how to put the html and css together, it gives me a flag when i do.